# Creating synthetic data in python with Agent-based modelling

Tags: python, machine-learning, agent-based-modeling, synthetic

To create synthetic data there are two approaches:

1. Drawing values according to some distribution or collection of distributions
2. Agent-based modelling

For the first approach we can use the `numpy.random.choice` function which gets a dataframe and creates rows according to the distribution of the data frame.

I wanted to ask if there is a defined function for the second approach "Agent-based modelling" in python or have we implement it on ourself?

Comment: What you ask is unclear. The assertion you made for the approaches is, at best, partial & incomplete (source?); agent-based modelling is a whole scientific topic in itself (see tag description for starters)...

Comment: @desertnaut Everywhere I read about synthetic data for ML these two approaches are mentioned. Here one source: https://www.codementor.io/ericlefort/my-thoughts-on-synthetic-data-kq719a5ss#background-on-synthetic-data

Comment: That's very surprising; *simulation*, in general (of which ABM is a branch) yes, but ABM in particular? Sounds bogus...

Comment: @desertnaut I think he means that we use the given data to train a model (ABM) which after that is able to output synthetic data

Comment: And here another source: https://www.riaktr.com/synthetic-data-become-major-competitive-advantage/

Comment: ABM models are not trained, and they (normally) do not take data as an input...